# How can I convert nested JSON to CSV on command line?

Tags: json, csv, jq

I have a JSON file who I am trying to convert to CSV using jq, but I've been having a lot of problems, this is the JSON:

```
{
    "nhits": 2,
    "parameters": {
        "dataset": "real-time-bezettingen-fietsenstallingen-gent",
        "rows": 10,
        "start": 0,
        "facet": [
            "facilityname"
        ],
        "format": "json",
        "timezone": "UTC"
    },
    "records": [
        {
            "datasetid": "real-time-bezettingen-fietsenstallingen-gent",
            "recordid": "d471594688a931ba8d81f8d883874a08cee84775",
            "fields": {
                "id": "48-2",
                "freeplaces": 71,
                "facilityname": "Braunplein",
                "geo_point_2d": [
                    51.05406845807926,
                    3.723722319130363
                ],
                "time": "2022-11-10T12:18:01+00:00",
                "totalplaces": 116,
                "occupiedplaces": 45,
                "bezetting": 38
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    3.723722319130363,
                    51.05406845807926
                ]
            },
            "record_timestamp": "2022-11-10T12:18:04.838Z"
        },
        {
            "datasetid": "real-time-bezettingen-fietsenstallingen-gent",
            "recordid": "d0121748cf31c7e1c02d99712bdf07cb33156689",
            "fields": {
                "id": "48-1",
                "freeplaces": 65,
                "facilityname": "Korenmarkt",
                "geo_point_2d": [
                    51.05388288288933,
                    3.7214177570400473
                ],
                "time": "2022-11-10T12:18:01+00:00",
                "totalplaces": 235,
                "occupiedplaces": 170,
                "bezetting": 72
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    3.7214177570400473,
                    51.05388288288933
                ]
            },
            "record_timestamp": "2022-11-10T12:18:04.838Z"
        }
    ],
    "facet_groups": [
        {
            "name": "facilityname",
            "facets": [
                {
                    "name": "Braunplein",
                    "count": 1,
                    "state": "displayed",
                    "path": "Braunplein"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Korenmarkt",
                    "count": 1,
                    "state": "displayed",
                    "path": "Korenmarkt"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I only want to have the columns facilityname, time, totalplaces, occupiedplaces and bezetting, I tried converting using the following command:

`jq -r '["naam", "tijd", "totaalAantalPlaatsen", "bezettePlaatsen", "bezetting"] , .records[] | (.fields[] | [.facilityname, .time, .totalplaces, .occupiedplaces, .bezetting]) | @csv' data.json`

But I get the error:

`jq: error (at data.json:0): Cannot index array with string "fields"`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You just need some parentheses around the `.records[] ...` part

```bash
jq -r '
  ["name",  "tijd", "totaalAantalPlaatsen", "bezettePlaatsen", "bezetting"],
  (.records[].fields | [.facilityname, .time, .totalplaces, .occupiedplaces, .bezetting])
  | @csv
' file.json
```